# pdf not printed correctly (text overlap) in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, pdf, printing

i'm using [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package to print waybill on network/wifi printer , the problem is when printing the pdf document it shows overlapping text on the paper as the picture below shows:
[document after printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/resv1.png)
although in document preview before printing the text is showed normally like this :
[document in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3uXy.png)

this is the code that generates the document:

```
static pw.Center getPdfWaybill(
     {required pw.Font arabicFont,required BuildContext cont, required String langID, required Order order}) {
   PdfColor borderColor = PdfColors.black;
   double fontSize = 12;
   var date = new DateTime.now();
   String currentDate = "${date.toString().split(" ")[0]}";
   return  pw.Center(child:
     pw.Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.start,
         crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
           pw.BarcodeWidget(
               barcode: pw.Barcode.fromType(pw.BarcodeType.Code93),
               data: order.getOrderId,
               width: 80,
               padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
               textStyle: pw.TextStyle(
                   fontSize: fontSize,
                   font: arabicFont,
                   letterSpacing: 0),
               height: 80),
           pw.SizedBox(height: 10),
           pw.Text("Print date: ${currentDate}",
             textDirection: pw.TextDirection.ltr,
             textScaleFactor: 1,
             style: pw.TextStyle(
                 inherit: true,
                 fontSize: fontSize,
                 font: arabicFont,
                 letterSpacing: 0),
           ),
           pw.SizedBox(height: 10),
           pw.Container(
               width: 150,
               padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
               decoration:
               pw.BoxDecoration(border: pw.Border.all(color: borderColor)),
               child: pw.Column(children: [
                 pw.Align(
                   child:pw.Text("Receiver Info",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                           fontSize: fontSize, font: arabicFont, letterSpacing: 0)), ),

                 pw.Divider(
                   thickness: 2,
                   color: PdfColors.grey,
                 ),

                 pw.Align(
                   alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                   child: pw.Text("Rec Name",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontSize: fontSize,
                           font: arabicFont,
                           letterSpacing: 0)),
                 ),
                 pw.Align(
                   alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                   child: pw.Text("to address ",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontSize: fontSize,
                           font: arabicFont,
                           letterSpacing: 0)),
                 ),
                 pw.Align(
                   alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                   child: pw.Text("to city",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontSize: fontSize,
                           font: arabicFont,
                           letterSpacing: 0)),
                 ),
                 pw.Align(
                   alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                   child: pw.Text("rec phone",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontSize: fontSize,
                           font: arabicFont,
                           letterSpacing: 0)),
                 )
               ])),
           pw.SizedBox(height: 10),

           pw.Container(
               width: 150,
               padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
               decoration:
               pw.BoxDecoration(border: pw.Border.all(color: borderColor)),
               child: pw.Column(children: [
                 pw.Align(
                   child:pw.Text("Sender Info",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                           fontSize: fontSize, font: arabicFont, letterSpacing: 0)), ),

                 pw.Divider(
                   thickness: 2,
                   color: PdfColors.grey,
                 ),

                 pw.Align(
                   alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                   child: pw.Text("pickup name",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontSize: fontSize,
                           font: arabicFont,
                           letterSpacing: 0)),
                 ),


               ])),
           pw.SizedBox(height: 10),
           pw.Container(
               width: 150,
               padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
               decoration:
               pw.BoxDecoration(border: pw.Border.all(color: borderColor)),
               child: pw.Column(children: [
                 pw.Align(
                   child:pw.Text("Amount",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontSize: fontSize, font: arabicFont, letterSpacing: 0)), ),

                 pw.Divider(
                   thickness: 2,
                   color: PdfColors.grey,
                 ),
                 pw.Align(
                   alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                   child: pw.Text("${order.getCod} NIS",
                       style: pw.TextStyle(
                           fontSize: fontSize+5,
                           font: arabicFont,
                           fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                           letterSpacing: 0)),
                 ),


               ])),



         ]));

 }
```

and this is the function that triggers generating and printing pdf:

```
 void printBill() async {
      try {
         final arabicFont = await rootBundle.load('assets/fonts/arial-unicode-ms.ttf');
         final doc = pw.Document();
         doc.addPage(
            new pw.Page(textDirection: pw.TextDirection.ltr,
            orientation: pw.PageOrientation.portrait,
            pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
            build: (cont) {
             return BillDocuments.getPdfWaybill(arabicFont: pw.Font.ttf(arabicFont),
                cont: context,
                langID: AppGeneralInfo.instance.langId,
                 order: order!);
           }));

          Uint8List pdfBytes = await doc.save();
          Printing.layoutPdf(
             format: PdfPageFormat.a4,
             usePrinterSettings: true,
             dynamicLayout: false,
             name: "bill",
             onLayout: (format) {
                print("layoutPdf invoked");
                return pdfBytes;
               });

         print("printer info : ${await Printing.info()}");

        } catch (e) {
           print("print bill exception: ${e}");
         }
    }
```

note : the printer(hp color laser jet m254nw) prints normally when i try to print other documents on my device so I assume the problem is not from the printer

I have tried these solutions :

- reducing the font size to 6
- changing font to different font families including arial , cairo , neosansarabic
- reducing the document to single Text widget

but didn't solve the problem